# Java nullpointer Exception: cannot invoke "com.razorpay.Order.toString()"because "order" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot-starter

```java
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.entities.Users;
import com.example.demo.services.UsersService;
import com.razorpay.Order;
import com.razorpay.RazorpayClient;
import com.razorpay.RazorpayException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller

public class PaymentController {
  @Autowired UsersService service;

  @GetMapping("/pay")
  public String pay() {
    return "pay";
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("finally")
  @PostMapping("/createOrder")
  @ResponseBody
  public String createOrder(HttpSession session) {
    int amount = 5000;
    Order order = null;
    try {
      RazorpayClient razorpay = new RazorpayClient(
          "rzp_test_pvGIc9JvXWZTVS", "UlnLCUb8lRxvBKRyIYRYWrEO");

      JSONObject orderRequest = new JSONObject();
      orderRequest.put(
          "amount", amount * 100); // amount in the smallest currency unit
      orderRequest.put("currency", "INR");
      orderRequest.put("receipt", "order_rcptid_11");

      order = razorpay.orders.create(orderRequest);

      String mail = (String) session.getAttribute("email");

      Users u = service.getUser(mail);
      u.setPremium(true);
      service.updateUser(u);

    } catch (RazorpayException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      return order.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Returning in a `finally` block is not a good practice.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Razorpay library, but did you try to debug your code? Like putting some logging between the lines? e.g. print the order object rightg after you assign it. And as @seenukarthi also said, dont put your return statement inside of the finally, it will produce NullPointerException at least on every RazorpayException.

Comment: Also i hope `new RazorpayClient(
          "rzp_test_pvGIc9JvXWZTVS", "UlnLCUb8lRxvBKRyIYRYWrEO");` these are not your real credientials. If these are real credentials I advice you to revoke these credentials and create a new one. Do not share credentials on a public site like stackoverflow.